# Making the enter key function like tab key

Tags: javascript, php, key, enter

Friends ,I know there are already many solutions to this question and i have used one but for some unknown reason it is not working in my application.So please help me out and let me know where am i going wrong.Please don't mark this question as duplicate.I seriously need your help.
Thanks in advance.
here is what i have tried.

```
// Catch the keydown for the entire document
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

  // Set self as the current item in focus
  var self = $(':focus'),
      // Set the form by the current item in focus
      form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'),
      focusable;

  // Array of Indexable/Tab-able items
  focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea,div[contenteditable=true]').filter(':visible');

  function enterKey(){
    if (e.which === 13 && !self.is('textarea,div[contenteditable=true]')) { // [Enter] key

      // If not a regular hyperlink/button/textarea
      if ($.inArray(self, focusable) && (!self.is('a,button'))){
        // Then prevent the default [Enter] key behaviour from submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();
      } // Otherwise follow the link/button as by design, or put new line in textarea

      // Focus on the next item (either previous or next depending on shift)
      focusable.eq(focusable.index(self) + (e.shiftKey ? -1 : 1)).focus();

      return false;
    }
  }
  // We need to capture the [Shift] key and check the [Enter] key either way.
  if (e.shiftKey) { enterKey() } else { enterKey() }
});
```

html code-

```
<form id="purchase" action="p_senddata.php" method="POST" >
   Bill_no:<input type="text" name="p_billno" id="pbillno"    /><br />
   Date:<input type="text" name="p_date" id="pdate"  /><br />
   Name of party:<input type="text" name="p_nameofparty" id="pnameofparty" /><br /><br />

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: there you go..@Sinto

Comment: Are you search to do http://jsfiddle.net/TnEB5/3/

Comment: Yes i tried that as well..but no it is not working ..It is submitting the form...Do i need to call this javascript function in html?@Sinto

Comment: Do you check fiddle. after entering first just press enter to move to next text field. e.preventDefault(); prevents submission on enter key press.

Comment: what you want to do it like , if i fill "Bill_no" and press enter it will be go to "Date" field,if i fill "Date" and press enter it will be go to "Name of party" field, if i fill "Name of party" and click enter it will submit, right ?

Comment: yes..exactly..@BrijalSavaliya

Comment: it is not helping ...i tried that as well @Sinto